# How does scrapy accomplish cookie communication

Tags: scrapy

When I'm writing scrapy framework, I come across a website that needs to be logged in. I want to request the cookie value in middlewares, so that the crawler can determine whether it needs to log in and retrieve the cookie value by the response status value.

I've tried to write the login code in `process_response` in middlewares to get the cookie after login.

**middleware.py**

```
def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
    print(response)  #但是这里不输出
    if len(response.body)<200:
        cks= self.get_cookies()
        request.headers['Cookie']=cks
        return request
    else：
        return response
```

**items.py**

```
class EsasentinelmissionItem(scrapy.Item):
     # define the fields for your item here like:
     url = scrapy.Field()#下载链接
```

**spider.py**

```
def parse(self,response):
     item=EsasentinelmissionItem()
     for url in urls:
          item['url']=url
          yield scrapy.Request(item)
```

I want to know cookie delivery intelligence in scrapy.

Comment: Are you aware that scrapy already has `CookieMiddleware`? You probably just need to have the spider do a `login` first before following any other links, and the rest will sort itself out. See the [example](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-userlogin) in the scrapy docs for instance.

Comment: One you login, the those cookies are used automatically in all upcoming requests that you yield from same callback method